# Can't Get BMP Image into rectangle OpenGL

Tags: c, image, opengl, graphics, bmp

so I have a 3D coordinate system. In this figure:

[image]

so I am trying to get a bmp image onto the rectangle to replace the letters A and B so that the image fits into the rectangle, but no matter what I do, either the image is a red square just like in the figure, or the image loads but the rest of the lines are colored black. How would I put the image onto the rectangle where the letters A and B are?

```
#define UpperBD 80
#define PI      3.1415926
#define Num_pts 10
using namespace std;
float Xe = 200.0f;//100
float Ye = 300.0f;
float Ze = 450.0f;
float Rho = sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2) + pow(Ze,2));
float D_focal = 100.0f; 
GLuint texture[2];

struct Image {
    unsigned long sizeX;
    unsigned long sizeY;
    char *data;
};
typedef struct Image Image;


#define checkImageWidth 64
#define checkImageHeight 64

GLubyte checkImage[checkImageWidth][checkImageHeight][3];
void makeCheckImage(void){

    int i, j, c;
    for (i = 0; i < checkImageWidth; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < checkImageHeight; j++) {
            c = ((((i&0x8)==0)^((j&0x8)==0)))*255;
            checkImage[i][j][0] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][1] = (GLubyte) c;
            checkImage[i][j][2] = (GLubyte) c;
        }
    }
}

int ImageLoad(char *filename, Image *image) {

    FILE *file;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long i; 
    unsigned short int planes; 
    unsigned short int bpp; 
    char temp; 

    if ((file = fopen(filename, "rb"))==NULL){
        printf("File Not Found : %s\n",filename);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 18, SEEK_CUR);
    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeX, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading width from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(&image->sizeY, 4, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading height from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    size = image->sizeX * image->sizeY * 3;

    if ((fread(&planes, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading planes from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    if (planes != 1) {
        printf("Planes from %s is not 1: %u\n", filename, planes);
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(&bpp, 2, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading bpp from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    if (bpp != 24) {
        printf("Bpp from %s is not 24: %u\n", filename, bpp);
        return 0;
    }

    fseek(file, 24, SEEK_CUR);

    image->data = (char *) malloc(size);
    if (image->data == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating memory for color-corrected image data");
        return 0;
    }

    if ((i = fread(image->data, size, 1, file)) != 1) {
        printf("Error reading image data from %s.\n", filename);
        return 0;
    }

    for (i=0;i<size;i+=3) { // reverse all of the colors. (bgr -> rgb)
        temp = image->data[i];
        image->data[i] = image->data[i+2];
        image->data[i+2] = temp;
    }

    // we're done.
    return 1;
}

Image * loadTexture(){

    Image *image1;

    // allocate space for texture
    image1 = (Image *) malloc(sizeof(Image));
    if (image1 == NULL) {
        printf("Error allocating space for image");
        exit(0);
    }

    if (!ImageLoad("g.bmp", image1)) {
        exit(1);
    }

    return image1;
}

void myinit(void)
//something in this function is making it not appear properly
{
   // glClearColor (0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0);
   // glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   // glDepthFunc(GL_LESS);

    Image *image1 = loadTexture();
    if(image1 == NULL){
        printf("Image was not returned from loadTexture\n");
        exit(0);
    }

  //  makeCheckImage();
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);

    // Create Texture
    glGenTextures(2, texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); 
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR); //scale linearly when image smalled than texture
   // glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, image1->sizeX, image1->sizeY, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image1->data);
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);
  //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
   // glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
  //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
  //  glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
   // glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL);
  //  glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, checkImageWidth, checkImageHeight, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,&checkImage[0][0][0]);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   // glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}


typedef struct {
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
    float Z[UpperBD];
} pworld;

typedef struct {
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
    float Z[UpperBD];
} pviewer;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} pperspective;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} pattern2DL;

typedef struct{
    float X[UpperBD];
    float Y[UpperBD];
} arrowpoint;

typedef struct {
    float r[UpperBD], g[UpperBD], b[UpperBD];
} pt_diffuse;

void mydisplay()
{

    float p1x=-1.0f,  p1y= 0.0f;   
    float p2x= 1.0f,  p2y= 0.0f;
    float p3x= 0.0f,  p3y= 1.0f;
    float p4x= 0.0f,  p4y=-1.0f;

    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();

    pworld  world;
    pviewer viewer;
    pperspective perspective;
    pattern2DL letterL;
    arrowpoint arrow;


    world.X[0] = 0.0;    world.Y[0] =  0.0;   world.Z[0] =  0.0;   
    world.X[1] = 50.0;   world.Y[1] =  0.0;   world.Z[1] =  0.0;   
    world.X[2] = 0.0;    world.Y[2] =  50.0;  world.Z[2] =  0.0;   
    world.X[3] = 0.0;    world.Y[3] =  0.0;   world.Z[3] =  50.0;   

    world.X[4] = 60.0;   world.Y[4] = -50.0;   world.Z[4] =  0.0;    
    world.X[5] = 60.0;   world.Y[5] =  50.0;   world.Z[5] =  0.0;    
    world.X[7] = 60.0;   world.Y[7] = -50.0;   world.Z[7] = 100.0;   
    world.X[6] = 60.0;   world.Y[6] =  50.0;   world.Z[6] =  100.0;    


    //define 2D pattern letter A
    letterL.X[0] = -10.0; letterL.Y[0] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[1] = -15.0; letterL.Y[1] = 10.0; 
    letterL.X[2] = -20.0; letterL.Y[2] = 30.0;    
    letterL.X[3] = -40.0; letterL.Y[3] = 30.0;
    letterL.X[4] = -45.0; letterL.Y[4] = 10.0;  
    letterL.X[5] = -50.0; letterL.Y[5] = 10.0;
    letterL.X[6] = -37.0; letterL.Y[6] = 70.0;
    letterL.X[7] = -23.0; letterL.Y[7] = 70.0;
    letterL.X[8] = -25.0; letterL.Y[8] = 40.0;
    letterL.X[9] = -35.0; letterL.Y[9] = 40.0;
    letterL.X[10] = -30.0; letterL.Y[10] = 60.0;

    //letter B
    letterL.X[11] = 10.0; letterL.Y[11] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[12] = 10.0; letterL.Y[12] = 70.0; 
    letterL.X[13] = 20.0; letterL.Y[13] = 10.0;    
    letterL.X[14] = 20.0; letterL.Y[14] = 70.0;

    letterL.X[15] = 20.0; letterL.Y[15] = 60.0;  
    letterL.X[16] = 20.0; letterL.Y[16] = 45.0;
    letterL.X[17] = 20.0; letterL.Y[17] = 35.0;
    letterL.X[18] = 20.0; letterL.Y[18] = 20.0;

    letterL.X[19] = 25.0; letterL.Y[19] = 58.0;
    letterL.X[20] = 27.0; letterL.Y[20] = 56.0;
    letterL.X[21] = 28.0; letterL.Y[21] = 52.0;
    letterL.X[22] = 27.0; letterL.Y[22] = 49.0;
    letterL.X[23] = 25.0; letterL.Y[23] = 47.0;

    letterL.X[24] = 25.0; letterL.Y[24] = 33.0;
    letterL.X[25] = 27.0; letterL.Y[25] = 31.0;
    letterL.X[26] = 28.0; letterL.Y[26] = 27.0;
    letterL.X[27] = 27.0; letterL.Y[27] = 24.0;
    letterL.X[28] = 25.0; letterL.Y[28] = 22.0;

    letterL.X[29] = 30.0; letterL.Y[29] = 65.0;
    letterL.X[30] = 34.0; letterL.Y[30] = 60.0;
    letterL.X[31] = 34.0; letterL.Y[31] = 50.0;
    letterL.X[32] = 30.0; letterL.Y[32] = 45.0;

    letterL.X[33] = 25.0; letterL.Y[33] = 40.0;

    letterL.X[34] = 30.0; letterL.Y[34] = 38.0;
    letterL.X[35] = 34.0; letterL.Y[35] = 30.0;
    letterL.X[36] = 34.0; letterL.Y[36] = 20.0;
    letterL.X[37] = 30.0; letterL.Y[37] = 15.0;

    arrow.X[0] = 0.0; arrow.Y[0] = 25.0;    
    arrow.X[1] = 0.0; arrow.Y[1] = 75.0; 
    arrow.X[2] = 60.0; arrow.Y[2] = 75.0;    
    arrow.X[3] = 60.0; arrow.Y[3] = 85.0;
    arrow.X[4] = 90.0; arrow.Y[4] = 50.0;  
    arrow.X[5] = 60.0; arrow.Y[5] = 15.0;
    arrow.X[6] = 60.0; arrow.Y[6] = 25.0;

    arrow.X[7] = 0.0; arrow.Y[7] = 25.0;    
    arrow.X[8] = 0.0; arrow.Y[8] = 75.0; 
    arrow.X[9] = 60.0; arrow.Y[9] = 75.0;    
    arrow.X[10] = 60.0; arrow.Y[10] = 85.0;
    arrow.X[11] = 90.0; arrow.Y[11] = 50.0;  
    arrow.X[12] = 60.0; arrow.Y[12] = 15.0;
    arrow.X[13] = 60.0; arrow.Y[13] = 25.0;

    //decoration
    for(int i = 0; i <= 37; i++)
    {
      world.X[8+i] = 60.0;
      world.Y[8+i] = letterL.X[i];
      world.Z[8+i] = letterL.Y[i];
    }
    //arrow
    for(int j = 0; j <= 6; j++)
    {
      world.X[46+j] = arrow.X[j]-50;//-50
      world.Y[46+j] = arrow.Y[j];
      world.Z[46+j] = 100.0;//CHANGE TO 150?
    }
    for(int k = 0; k <= 6; k++)
    {
      world.X[53+k] = arrow.X[k]-50;
      world.Y[53+k] = arrow.Y[k];
      world.Z[53+k] = 110.0;//CHANGE TO 150?
    }

    float sPheta = Ye / sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2));
    float cPheta = Xe / sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2));
    float sPhi = sqrt(pow(Xe,2) + pow(Ye,2)) / Rho;
    float cPhi = Ze / Rho;

    float xMin = 1000.0, xMax = -1000.0;
    float yMin = 1000.0, yMax = -1000.0;


    world.X[60] = -200.0;   world.Y[60]=50.0;   world.Z[60]=200.0;//ps
    world.X[61] = 0.0;   world.Y[61]=0.0;   world.Z[61]=0.0;//vector a
    world.X[62] = 0.0;   world.Y[62]=0.0;   world.Z[62]=1.0;//VECTOR N

    float tmp = (world.X[62]*(world.X[61]-world.X[60]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[61]-world.Y[60]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[61]-world.Z[60]));
                cout << tmp;
    float lambda =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[7]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[7]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[7])));
                cout << lambda;
    float lambda_2 = tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[6]))//MAKE ARROW HIGHER, ABOVE PROJECTION PLANE SQUARE
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[6]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[6])));
                cout << lambda_2;
    world.X[63] = world.X[60]+lambda*(world.X[60]-world.X[7]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[63] = world.Y[60]+lambda*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[7]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[63] = 0.0;

    world.X[64] = world.X[60]+lambda_2*(world.X[60]-world.X[6]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[64] = world.Y[60]+lambda_2*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[6]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[64] = 0.0;


    //for arrow's shade, 46-52
    float lambda_arrow1 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[46]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[46]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[46])));

    float lambda_arrow2 = tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[47]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[47]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[47])));

    float lambda_arrow3 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[48]))
                            +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[48]))
                            +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[48])));

    float lambda_arrow4 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[49]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[49]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[49])));

    float lambda_arrow5 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[50]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[50]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[50])));

    float lambda_arrow6 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[51]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[51]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[51])));

    float lambda_arrow7 =  tmp/((world.X[62]*(world.X[60]-world.X[52]))
                +(world.Y[62]*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[52]))
                +(world.Z[62]*(world.Z[60]-world.Z[52])));

    world.X[65] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow1*(world.X[60]-world.X[46]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[65] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow1*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[46]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[65] = 0.0;

    world.X[66] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow2*(world.X[60]-world.X[47]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[66] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow2*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[47]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[66] = 0.0;

    world.X[67] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow3*(world.X[60]-world.X[48]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[67] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow3*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[48]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[67] = 0.0;

    world.X[68] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow4*(world.X[60]-world.X[49]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[68] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow4*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[49]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[68] = 0.0;

    world.X[69] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow5*(world.X[60]-world.X[50]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[69] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow5*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[50]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[69] = 0.0;

    world.X[70] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow6*(world.X[60]-world.X[51]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[70] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow6*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[51]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[70] = 0.0;


    world.X[71] = world.X[60]+lambda_arrow7*(world.X[60]-world.X[52]);//interseciton point for p7, X COMP
    world.Y[71] = world.Y[60]+lambda_arrow7*(world.Y[60]-world.Y[52]);//Y COMP
    world.Z[71] = 0.0;

    pt_diffuse  diffuse;   //diffuse.r[3]

    #define     Kdr     0.8
    #define     Kdg     0.0
    #define     Kdb     0.0

    float distance[UpperBD];
    for (int i=63; i<=71; i++) {
    distance[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2)+         //intersect pt p7
                        pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[60]),2)+
                        pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2) );

    } 

    //--------compute angle---------------------*
    float angle[UpperBD], tmp_dotProd[UpperBD], tmp_mag_dotProd[UpperBD]; 

    for (int i=63; i<=71; i++){

        tmp_dotProd[i] = world.Z[i]-world.X[60]; 
        std::cout << " tmp_dotProd[i]  " <<  tmp_dotProd[i] << std::endl;

        tmp_mag_dotProd[i] = sqrt(pow((world.X[i]-world.X[60]),2)+         //[45] pt light source 
                            pow((world.Y[i]-world.Y[60]),2)+
                            pow((world.Z[i]-world.Z[60]),2) );
        std::cout << " tmp_mag_dotProd[i]  1 " <<  tmp_mag_dotProd[i] << std::endl;

        angle[i] = tmp_dotProd[i]/ tmp_mag_dotProd[i]; 
        std::cout << "angle[i]  " << angle[i] << std::endl;

        //compute color intensity
        diffuse.r[i] = Kdr *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
        diffuse.g[i] = Kdg *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
        diffuse.b[i] = Kdb *  angle[i] /  pow(distance[i],2) ;
    }


    for(int i = 0; i < UpperBD; i++)
    {
        viewer.X[i] = -sPheta * world.X[i] + cPheta * world.Y[i];
        viewer.Y[i] = -cPheta * cPhi * world.X[i] 
                 - cPhi * sPheta * world.Y[i]
                 + sPhi * world.Z[i];
        viewer.Z[i] = -sPhi * cPheta * world.X[i]
                 - sPhi * cPheta * world.Y[i]
                 -cPheta * world.Z[i] + Rho;
                // cout << i;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)
    {
        perspective.X[i] = D_focal * viewer.X[i] / viewer.Z[i] ;
        perspective.Y[i] = D_focal * viewer.Y[i] / viewer.Z[i] ;
        if (perspective.X[i] > xMax) xMax = perspective.X[i];
        if (perspective.X[i] < xMin) xMin = perspective.X[i];
        if (perspective.Y[i] > yMax) yMax = perspective.Y[i];
        if (perspective.Y[i] < yMin) yMin = perspective.Y[i]; 

    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= UpperBD; i++)
    {
        if ((xMax-xMin) != 0) perspective.X[i] = perspective.X[i]/(xMax-xMin);
        if ((yMax-yMin) != 0) perspective.Y[i] = perspective.Y[i]/(yMax-yMin);
        std::cout << i << perspective.X[i] << perspective.Y[i] << std::endl;
    }


    glBegin(GL_LINES);

      glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
      glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[1],perspective.Y[1]);
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[2],perspective.Y[2]);
      glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[0],perspective.Y[0]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[3],perspective.Y[3]);

      glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);  // projection plane , THE RECTANGLE WITH THE LETTERS
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[6],perspective.Y[6]); 
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[7],perspective.Y[7]);
     glEnd();

      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  // LETTER A STARTS HERE
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
           glVertex2f(perspective.X[13],perspective.Y[13]);
        glVertex2f(perspective.X[12],perspective.Y[12]);
       //etc...


          glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);



         glVertex2f(perspective.X[8],perspective.Y[8]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[15],perspective.Y[15]);

          //etc...

         glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glVertex2f(perspective.X[16],perspective.Y[16]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[17],perspective.Y[17]);
      //etc...


         glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);  //LETTER B STARTS HERE
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

        glVertex2f(perspective.X[19],perspective.Y[19]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[20],perspective.Y[20]);

          //etc...

     glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    //     
           glVertex2f(perspective.X[23],perspective.Y[23]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);


         glVertex2f(perspective.X[25],perspective.Y[25]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[26],perspective.Y[26]);



          glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);


      glVertex2f(perspective.X[27],perspective.Y[27]);
      glVertex2f(perspective.X[28],perspective.Y[28]);

     //etc...


          glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);




            glVertex2f(perspective.X[29],perspective.Y[29]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[30],perspective.Y[30]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[30],perspective.Y[30]);





           glVertex2f(perspective.X[40],perspective.Y[40]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[39],perspective.Y[39]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[40],perspective.Y[40]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[41],perspective.Y[41]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[41],perspective.Y[41]);



          glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0); 
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[24],perspective.Y[24]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[41],perspective.Y[41]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[25],perspective.Y[25]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[32],perspective.Y[32]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[33],perspective.Y[33]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[32],perspective.Y[32]);

              glVertex2f(perspective.X[33],perspective.Y[33]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[34],perspective.Y[34]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[42],perspective.Y[42]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[41],perspective.Y[41]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[42],perspective.Y[42]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[43],perspective.Y[43]);

           glEnd();
      glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);




           glVertex2f(perspective.X[35],perspective.Y[35]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[34],perspective.Y[34]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[35],perspective.Y[35]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[36],perspective.Y[36]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[26],perspective.Y[26]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[36],perspective.Y[36]);










            glVertex2f(perspective.X[44],perspective.Y[44]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[43],perspective.Y[43]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[44],perspective.Y[44]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[45],perspective.Y[45]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[21],perspective.Y[21]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[45],perspective.Y[45]);



    glEnd();

    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);//3D arrow starts here

    glVertex2f(perspective.X[46],perspective.Y[46]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[47],perspective.Y[47]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[48],perspective.Y[48]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[49],perspective.Y[49]);


    glVertex2f(perspective.X[50],perspective.Y[50]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[51],perspective.Y[51]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[52],perspective.Y[52]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[51],perspective.Y[51]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[49],perspective.Y[49]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[50],perspective.Y[50]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[48],perspective.Y[48]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[47],perspective.Y[47]);
    //      
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[52],perspective.Y[52]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[46],perspective.Y[46]);






          glVertex2f(perspective.X[53],perspective.Y[53]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[54],perspective.Y[54]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[55],perspective.Y[55]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[56],perspective.Y[56]);


    glVertex2f(perspective.X[57],perspective.Y[57]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[58],perspective.Y[58]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[59],perspective.Y[59]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[58],perspective.Y[58]);
    //     
            glVertex2f(perspective.X[56],perspective.Y[56]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[57],perspective.Y[57]);
    //     
     glVertex2f(perspective.X[55],perspective.Y[55]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[54],perspective.Y[54]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[59],perspective.Y[59]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[53],perspective.Y[53]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[46],perspective.Y[46]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[46+7],perspective.Y[46+7]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[47],perspective.Y[47]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[47+7],perspective.Y[47+7]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[48],perspective.Y[48]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[48+7],perspective.Y[48+7]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[49],perspective.Y[49]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[49+7],perspective.Y[49+7]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[50],perspective.Y[50]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[50+7],perspective.Y[50+7]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[51],perspective.Y[51]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[51+7],perspective.Y[51+7]);

       glEnd();    


          glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 0.0);
          glBegin(GL_LINES);

       glVertex2f(perspective.X[63],perspective.Y[63]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[64],perspective.Y[64]);

       glVertex2f(perspective.X[63],perspective.Y[63]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[4],perspective.Y[4]);

             glVertex2f(perspective.X[64],perspective.Y[64]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[5],perspective.Y[5]);

       glEnd();   


          glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 0.0);
          glBegin(GL_LINES);

             glVertex2f(perspective.X[65],perspective.Y[65]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[66],perspective.Y[66]);

             glVertex2f(perspective.X[67],perspective.Y[67]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[66],perspective.Y[66]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[67],perspective.Y[67]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[68],perspective.Y[68]);


          glVertex2f(perspective.X[69],perspective.Y[69]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[68],perspective.Y[68]);

          glVertex2f(perspective.X[69],perspective.Y[69]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[70],perspective.Y[70]);

           glVertex2f(perspective.X[71],perspective.Y[71]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[70],perspective.Y[70]);

            glVertex2f(perspective.X[71],perspective.Y[71]);
          glVertex2f(perspective.X[72],perspective.Y[72]);

    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[1]);

        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.1, -0.1, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.0);
        glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
        glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.1);
        glVertex3f(0.241421, 0.1, -0.141421);
        glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.1);
        glVertex3f(0.241421, -0.1, -0.141421);
        glEnd();

    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        #define     display_scaling        200000.0
        #define     display_shifting    0.2
        for (int i=63; i<=71; i++) {
            float r, g, b;
            r = display_scaling*diffuse.r[i]+display_shifting;

            g = diffuse.g[i]; b = diffuse.b[i] ;
            glColor3f(r, g, b);
            std::cout << "display_scaling*diffuse.r[i]  " << r << std::endl;
            glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
            glVertex2f(perspective.X[i],perspective.Y[i]);
            glVertex2f(perspective.X[i]+0.1,perspective.Y[i]);
            glVertex2f(perspective.X[i]+0.1,perspective.Y[i]+0.1);
            glVertex2f(perspective.X[i],perspective.Y[i]+0.1);
            glEnd();
        }

    glutSwapBuffers();
    glFlush();
}



int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc,argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutCreateWindow("lab");
    myinit();

    glutDisplayFunc(mydisplay);
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

Comment: Both your calls to `glTexImage2D()` are commented out. Since that's how you upload your texture to the GPU, you probably won't get an image until you uncomment  them. Is there a reason you commented them out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note, that drawing by `glBegin`/`glEnd` sequences, the fixed function pipeline matrix stack and fixed function pipeline per vertex light model, is deprecated since decades.
Read about [Fixed Function Pipeline](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Fixed_Function_Pipeline) and see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification) and [Shader](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader) for a state of the art way of rendering.

---

[`glTexImage2D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml) specifies the texture image. You have to reactivate the code, which you have commented out, because it loads the image date to the data sore of the texture object.

OpenGL is a state engine. If a state is set, it is kept stated until it is changed again. This mans if you want to draw a object with a texture, then you have to enable texturing (`glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D )`) before you draw the object and you have to disable it after (`glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D )`).

If texturing is enabled, then by default the color of the texel is multiplied by the current color, because by default the texture environment mode (`GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE`) is `GL_MODULATE`. See [`glTexEnv`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexEnv.xml).

This causes that the color of the texels of the texture is "mixed" by the last color which you have set by [`glColor4f`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glColor.xml).

Set a "white" color before you render the texture, to solve your issue:

```
glColor4f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
```

Likewise you can change the environment mode to `GL_REPLACE`, instead:

```
glTexEnvi(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_REPLACE);
```

e.g.

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.1, -0.1, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.0);
glVertex3f(0.1, 0.1, 0.0);
glTexCoord2f(0.1, 0.1);
glVertex3f(0.241421, 0.1, -0.141421);
glTexCoord2f(0.0, 0.1);
glVertex3f(0.241421, -0.1, -0.141421);
glEnd();

glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now the color is good, but another problem I keep having is that whenever I run the code everything is outputted incorrectly, take a look at this image: https://ibb.co/s3w4zX4    its all smashed together for some reason.